# Transfering files over bluetooth like in Android Bluetooth Chat Example

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

How to use Android Bluetooth Chat Example and chaneg it for file transfer. I want to transfer local SQLite database to another Android device via bluetooth.

I changed the example code (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html), but if I send file bigger than 1024 bytes long, then I get more events triggered in Handler class.
I tried to send small txt file and it's working (smaller than 1k).

Can somebody help me please.

Thanks,
Toni

Comment: Hi Toni...Have you implemented the File transfer successfully..Please Post the file writing/reading code.It would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read buffer in that example is set to 1024 bytes. After each read, which is max 1024 bytes long, it sends a message to the handler.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.html

(search for 1024)

Comment: Hi Peter.  I saw that, but how can I change it to bigger if my DB file will have differend filesize. Thank you, Toni

Comment: You don't. You create a loop and send several 1024-byte long chunks.

Comment: And how can I than join this chunks on reciver and conver them to file again. I know how to convert file from byte array.

Comment: Is there any examples for this? How the code is made in example, when I debug, I actually get loops if I send bigger file, but I don't know how to combine chunks to a single byte array.

Comment: Look at this example. This covers the sending side: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/CopyFile.html

Comment: On receiving side is a bit trickier, because you need to detect the end of stream. The easiest is to add a set of bytes which indicate end of stream and then detect this set of bytes when receiving data.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused where to put your purposed loop code, because now I convert my file via `byte[] data =org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File f)` and send filearray via `BluetoothService.write(data)`. It's the same with receiving. Thank you Peter, Toni

Comment: Don't put whole file into a byte array - this just wastes memory. Use example above where you have a buffer array and loop through file stream.

Comment: I managed to send it like 1024-byte chunks. I managed to detect the end of the stream with adding a set of bytes, like you suggested. Can you please tell me how can I join the chunks together into one byte array. Thank you, Toni

Comment: Create a `FileOutputStream` and write byte arrays to it. Watch for length - you should only write length taht you get when reading from bluetooth. Basically what you are doing is file copy (see example I linked) twice - first from file to bluetooth and second from bluetooth to file. You could almost copy the file copy example, except for the file ending marker which you need to add.